# Which puck has the greatest kinetic energy at the finish line?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

The question is:

> "Two pucks one with mass 3kg and the other with mass 1kg are pushed along a frictionless table with the same horizontal force from rest from the same starting point to the same finish line. Which of the pucks has the greatest kinetic energy at the finish line?"

I thought the pucks had the same kinetic energy at the finish line, but apparently thats wrong. Can someone explain? Is it the 3kg one because of the greater mass?

Comment: Why do you think they don't end up with the same kinetic energy?

Answer (score 3):

You can take a couple of approaches. GaryP has a good one.

Work done on a particle is the force applied through a distance. We are told that there is some distance $d$ through which both pucks are moved and they are both subject to the same force $F$.

Work is the change of kinetic energy $W=Fd$. F and d is the same for both. One can zoom in though.

A constant force implies a constant acceleration by Newton's second law. The pucks are starting from rest, the final velocity is $V$. So the average velocity is $(0+V)/2$. The acceleration is $(V-0)/t$ where $t$ is the time it takes the puck to traverse distance $d$. So $t=2d/V$. So $a=V^2/2d$. But $a=F/m$. So $Fd=mV^2/2$.

So while the kinetic energy is the same, $2Fd/m=V^2$. So velocity will be smaller for the more massive puck.